# Setting compression level in node zlib

Tags: node.js, zlib, jsxgraph

How do I force zlib to use compression level 9.
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/zlib.html

I need to set this since the browser side decompression file base64 encoded string compressed in level 9.
http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/jsxcompressor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the docs:

- https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_params_level_strategy_callback

> `zlib.params(level, strategy, callback)`
>
> Added in: v0.11.4
>
> Dynamically update the compression level and compression strategy. Only applicable to deflate algorithm.